# Are there known issues with QFtp for use with pure-ftpd?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, ftp, qt4

This is related to the question I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294985/qt-cannot-get-ftp-to-open-directory-correctly), but I hadn't gotten much visibility for that question so I wanted to ask in a more general way. I have a Qt 4.7 project that utilizes QFtp functionality. Until very recently we were using this with an FTP server that was vsftpd. Everything worked fine with it then. However, several days ago we moved the server to a new computer. All the contents are identical, but now it uses pure-ftpd instead of vsftpd. Since the move, none of my QFtp code works properly. Is there any known problems that arise when trying to use QFtp with this type of FTP server? I can't find anything helpful online, and it's rather frustrating not being able to find anything wrong with the code and yet having it not work. If anyone knows anything about this and could please share, I'd appreciate it a lot. Thanks!

Comment: FTP is FTP. Unless you wrote your own ftp interface to look for strings which are now no longer present because you've got a different FTP server, it shouldn't matter what the server version is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think I just figured *something* out... I had it run QFtp::list to go through the ftp and retrieve directories, then use list() again on those to retrieve the files in those subdirectories. Our subdirectories to get files out of had spaces in the name, eg "My Directory". Apparently, the vsftpd we were using before could handle this with no problem, but the pure-ftpd can't handle spaces in the directory names. When I switch it to something like "MyDirectory" or "My_Directory", the pure-ftpd works fine. I couldn't find anything online about this difference, but apparently it's there, because that fixed the issue I was having.